# Unable to allocate 47.5 MiB for an array with shape (1080, 1920, 3) and data type float64

Tags: python, numpy, ffmpeg, moviepy

Iam try to create a large video(longer than 3h)by CompositeVideoClip using moviepy.
The problem is it take too much ram (i have 32gb ram).It takes the whole ram (99%) by create a bunch of ffmpeg-win64-v4.2.2.exe ffmpeg-win64-v4.2.2.exe
[image: it takes the whole ram]

[image: it create a bunch of ffmpeg-win64-v4.2.2.exe ffmpeg-win64-v4.2.2.exe]

after it a while it said Unable to allocate 47.5 MiB for an array with shape (1080, 1920, 3) and data type float64.
here is my code :

```
def CombieVideo():
    global curentVideoLengt
    masterVideo = NULL
    for videoUrl in videoFiles:
        print(videoUrl)
        video = VideoFileClip(videoUrl).fx(vfx.fadein,1).fx(vfx.fadeout,1)
        curentVideoLengt += video.duration
        if curentVideoLengt >= (audioLen*60*60):
            break
        if masterVideo== NULL:
            masterVideo= video
        else:
            masterVideo = CompositeVideoClip([masterVideo,video])
            
    if curentVideoLengt < (audioLen*60*60):
        videoUrl=random.choice(videoFiles)
        print(videoUrl)
        video =video(videoUrl).fx(vfx.fadein,1).fx(vfx.fadeout,1)
        curentVideoLengt= curentVideoLengt+video.duration
        masterVideo = CompositeVideoClip([masterVideo,video])
        CombieVideo()
    else:
        masterVideo.audio = CompositeAudioClip(audios)
        masterVideo.write_videofile('./MasterVideo/output_video.avi', fps=30, threads=4, codec="png")
        
CombieVideo()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue isn't running allocating arrays, but rather you're opening too many instances of `FFMPEG_VideoReader` via `VideoFileClip` instances. Each of  `FFMPEG_VideoReader` spawns an instance of ffmpeg, which eats up your memory resource.

You can try to close the reader immediately after instantiation:

```py
video = VideoFileClip(videoUrl).fx(vfx.fadein,1).fx(vfx.fadeout,1)
video.close()

# continue as is
```

<strike>No guarantee if this will work, but it should points you in a right direction.</strike> This should fix your problem as `moviepy` documentation of `VideoFileClip` is suggesting for the immediate closure.

On a side note, do you really want to recurse this function? It's picking one random file then adding more files from the top of the `videoFiles` list if the random one isn't long enough.